# Detect installed adblocker in flutter

Tags: flutter, ads, adblock

family.

I just wanted to ask a quick question in Flutter:
I am creating an app that will promote musicians using video and image ads. I also rely on AdMob to generate profit. I don't propose another service other than this.

So I want to refuse access to users with AdBlock apps installed on their mobile.

Can someone tell me if it is achievable with flutter? If yes, what is the procedure to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

try to use this package, it can detect DOM, Opera and Brave blockers. But it only for web
https://pub.dev/packages/adblock_detecter